# The tagging rep is way too high.

Tags: discussion

I was unable to properly tag a question I have just asked because I need 150 rep to create a tag. But the tags on this site are highly specific, there was not a single tag that usefully describes my question.

The question is here: [How can I model this usage scenario mathematically?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/how-can-i-model-this-usage-scenario-mathematically)

Answer (score 7):

I do not think that the 150-rep hurdle of creating new tags is too high.  We should not create new tags easily for two reasons:

1. Having too many different tags renders tags useless for classification.
2. The fact that you do not find an appropriate tag *may* suggest that the question is not suitable for the site.  (I am not talking about any of your questions, but I am talking about a general idea.)

You should be familiar with how the site works to judge whether creating a new tag is appropriate or not.  I do not claim that the reputation system reflects each user’s familiarity with the site very well, but it is good enough in my opinion.

Also, as Suresh wrote, you can always suggest a desired tag in a question.  If someone with enough rep sees it and is convinced, he/she will create the tag.

Answer (score 4):

That's part of the system description. not sure if we can change that unilaterally for our site. As happens though, there are a sufficient number of >150 rep users that if you were to suggest a new tag in the answer, one of them would be happy to oblige (looks like this is what happened in your case)